# Printing all the information of tabbed windows

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way we can print all the information of tabbed on a single click instead of going to each tab and clicking the print button.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has an extension for this:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5142/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2513/

Comment: That's going to be browser specific then. I'm sure you can do a quick search for add-on/extensions for each browser you use.